# linear equations from two points in 3 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

- I have 4 points A, B, C, D in 3 dimensions. Point A is origin
  ([0,0,0]).
- Point D is on the line, between points A and B.

I need solve those things:

1. Find distance (D1) between points A and D.
2. Find new point E, which is on the line, between points A and C in same distance as D1

Comment: you need to write a formula or what?

Comment: @manu-fatto I need help with linear equations from two points in 3 dimensions. I know it how to do in 2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D_{1}=\sqrt{d_{1}^{2}+d_{2}^2+d_3^2}$ ,here $D=(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ .Now let $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and let $C=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ Let $X=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be any point on AC then we have (Using the formula of a straight line in 3-D)$$\frac{x_1-a_1}{c_1-a_1}=\frac{x_2-a_2}{c_2-a_2}=\frac{x_3-a_3}{c_3-a_3}$$
Now let all the above $\lambda$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{x_1-a_1}{c_1-a_1}=\frac{x_2-a_2}{c_2-a_2}=\frac{x_3-a_3}{c_3-a_3}=\lambda$$
Now find $x_i$ in terms of $\lambda$. And find $\lambda$ using the following relation.
$$\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^2+x_3^2}=D_{1}=\sqrt{d_{1}^{2}+d_{2}^2+d_3^2}$$
You are done.

Comment: Thanx for distance solution

Comment: Abhra-abir-kundu Absolutly perfect, thax a lot for your guide.

Comment: You are Welcome.... @JinDave